# Select2 Dropdown options disappear once I select any option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-select2

```
<select rows='3' name="user_id[]" required="required" multiple class="form-control select2" style="width: 100% !important">
    <?php
    $qid = $_GET['id'];
    $student = $conn->query('SELECT u.*,s.course as ls, s.branch, s.year FROM users u left join students s on u.id = s.user_id where u.user_type = 3 ');
    while ($row = $student->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_id = $row['id'];
        $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM quiz_student_list where quiz_id ="'.$qid.'" and user_id = "'.$user_id.'"');
        if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        ?>  
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo ucwords($row['name']) . ' ' . $row['ls'] . ' ' . $row['branch'] . ' ' . $row['year'] ?></option>
    <?php } 
    }
    ?>
</select>



$(".select2").select2({
    placeholder: "Select here",
    width: 'resolve'
});
```

[image]

I have a students dropdown in select2 jquery but suppose I click on any one of the name it got selected but the options disappears. I have to click again to see the students list and click again on any other name. I want to select multiple in one go only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".select2").select2({
    placeholder: "Select here",
    width: 'resolve',
    closeOnSelect: false
});
```

closeOnSelect: false
by using this property I have actually got what I was looking for. I have set it to false so that it doesn't get closed on selection of any one of the options.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for this suggestion, and by keeping this in mind I have edited it.